# Series repeating sheets in Altium

Tags: altium, led-strip

I need several number of WS2813 LEDs (20 LEDs), to be connected to each other in series, to form a strip ring.

Each WS2813 has an input DI (D1) which is generated by MCU and also has an output DO which must be connected to the DI pin of the next LED (D2, D3, D4, ...)

[image]

For preventing from multiple component placement, I think It's more efficient to use repeating sheets capability of Altium, but I don't know how implement it in series format.

[image]

Is there any way to do it in Altium?

Comment: "several number" like 3, or like 300?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to use REPEAT for this one. I think you'll have to draw the sheets individually. REPEAT is really used for parallel buses, not serial.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen if the exact number matters, It's 20 :)

Comment: It might be possible to use Repeat and buses to achieve the connectivity you want, but it will be very bad for communicating your design. If its only 20, just make the 20 sheet symbols (copy paste works), and connect them as intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the sheet symbol, then use Edit->Smart Paste and check Enable Paste Array and enable Text Increment, you can get your row or column of repeated sheet symbols. (You'll have to adjust the spacing depending on the size of the sheet symbol.) You will still need to connect the output and input ports manually but it will save you some time.

Answer (score 1):

Like @gcr says, just copy and paste the schematic sheet symbol (which should work well for 20 copies, but not so much for 300 ;-) ).

The added benefit by this approach is that each instance will be a class that you can use in individual rooms in PCB.  This allows you to route one room, and apply all of the same artwork, relativity easily, to the other 19 rooms (Copy Room Formats).

Good luck!